# What is the most efficient way to get the max size of a string column of a pandas dataframe, stored as a hdf5 file

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, hdf5

I have a very large pandas dataframe stored as a hdf5 file. To get the max size of a string column of this dataframe (df), I read this dataframe in chunks, and use the following code to get the result

```
df[col].str.len().max()
```

Is there a more efficient approach whereby I can read the metadata of the hdf5 to directly get its min_itemsize?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [26]: df = DataFrame({'A' : ['foo','b']})

In [27]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [28]: store.append('df',df,data_columns=True)
```

This will retrieve the dtype for a single column.

```
In [29]: store.get_storer('df').table.cols.A.dtype.itemsize
Out[29]: 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about table where data_columns are not set? The table columns info will be as follows, we can't get 'A' itemsize
/df1/table.cols (Cols), 2 columns
  index (Column(2,), int64)
  values_block_0 (Column(2, 1), ('S3', (1,)))

Comment: you'll have to extract it. the point is that these are conglomerated. Odd that you actually need this. what is the reason?

Comment: I need to do some data manipulations on a large table. What I do is I read the table in chunks, manipulate each chunk, append the chunk to a new table. But before doing these, I need to know in advance the itemsize of the string columns, which I will use to declare the new table.